# Catenary Between Two Points (Hanging Chain)

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

*This is one of several [challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2007/21682) left for the community by [Calvin's Hobbies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26997/calvins-hobbies).*

The curve that an idealised hanging rope or chain makes is a [catenary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary).

[image: A chain forming a catenary]
<sup>[Image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kettenkurve_0400.JPG) by Bin im Garten, via Wikimedia Commons. Used under the [CC-By-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en) licence.</sup>

Write a program that will draw a catenary, as an image, in quadrant 1 of the plane given two points *(x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>)*, *(x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>)*, and the "rope length" *L*. *L* will be greater than the distance between the two points.

You must also draw axes on the left and bottom sides of the image (400x400 px min) for scale. Only draw the quadrant from x and y in range 0 to 100. (You may assume the points are in range.)

Dots, or something similiar, should be drawn at the *(x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>)*, *(x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>)* endpoints to distinguish them. **The curve should only be drawn in the space between these points.**

Comment: How precise do we have to be? Does the image have to be anti-aliased? How wide must/can the line be?

Comment: We also assume that the curve itself (not just the points) is in range, right? Or would we draw two arcs cut by the axis if it goes below that?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@Sparr The image does not have to be anti-aliased. The line must be at least 1px thick. The catenary should be as accurate as your language's floating point arithmetic can do.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@Geobits You may also assume the curve is in range.

Comment: I was going to do this until I realized that the math might be slightly more complex than my current pre-calculus. Maybe next year.

Comment: What should the horizontal force be?

Comment: @BetaDecay I don't know what that is. Lets say its 0.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@MartinBüttner I still don't understand it - I had thought that with the two points and the length of rope, there would only be one catenary that resulted. All I can say is that the horizontal force should be such that it draws the same kind of curves as [this](https://github.com/valrus/catenary).

Comment: Just look up the Wikipedia article you linked to. The section on the mathematical description explains what the horizontal force is needed for.

Comment: @IngoBürk In the [image you're referring to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#mediaviewer/File:Catenary-tension.png) the centenaries clearly are not the same length. The question asks that the length of the curve **between the points** is L. If you let out the `a=1/2` line in that image until it was the same length as the `a=3` line, the curves would match up. The only catenary of the same length between those points is the up facing mirrored version.

Comment: @VonIlya It might be good to say that L will never be less than the distance between the endpoints.

Comment: Can we assume the given points will be distinct? (Specifically their x values)

Comment: @sto​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​kastic Yes.

Comment: Before I refine my answer, a couple of clarifications: 1.Can we assume the points will be given left to right (lower x value first) or can they be reversed? 2. I think I have misinterpreted the rules regarding the sizing. I have drawn my axes as 400x400 graphics units (which I have realised is only 200x200 pixels.) I will resize to 800x800 graphics units (400x400 pixels) and scale so that this corresponds to 100x100 mathematical units (x and y in range 0-100.)

Comment: @steveverrill 1. Yes. 2 Also Yes

Comment: @VonIlya 1. Is that yes we can assume the points will always be given left to right and not reversed?

Comment: @steveverrill Yes

Answer (score 5):

## Python + NumPy + Matplotlib, 1131

Just to get us started, here's an attempt that uses no knowledge of calculus or physics other than the fact that the catenary minimizes the energy of a chain. Hey, my algorithm may not be efficient, but at least it's not implemented efficiently either!

```python
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
length, x0, y0, x1, y1 = input(), input(), input(), input(), input()
chain = np.array([[x0] + [length / 1000.]*1000, [y0] + [0.] * 1000])
def rotate(angle, x, y):
 return x * math.cos(angle) + y * math.sin(angle), -x * math.sin(angle) + y  * math.cos(angle)
def eval(chain, x1, y1):
 mysum = chain.cumsum(1)
 springpotential = 1000 * ((mysum[0][-1] - x1) ** 2 + (mysum[1][-1] - y1)  ** 2)
 potential = mysum.cumsum(1)[1][-1]
 return springpotential + potential
def jiggle(chain, x1, y1):
 for _ in xrange(100000):
  pre = eval(chain, x1, y1)
  angle = random.random() * 2 * math.pi
  index = random.randint(1,1000)
  chain[0][index], chain[1][index] = rotate(angle, chain[0][index], chain[1][index])
  if( pre < eval(chain, x1, y1)):
   chain[0][index], chain[1][index] = rotate(-angle, chain[0][index], chain[1][index])
jiggle(chain, x1, y1)
sum = chain.cumsum(1)
x1 = 2 * x1 - sum[0][-1]
y1 = 2 * y1 - sum[1][-1]
jiggle(chain, x1, y1)
sum = chain.cumsum(1)
plt.plot(sum[0][1:], sum[1][1:])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

## BBC Basic, 300 ASCII characters, tokenised filesize 260

```
  INPUTr,s,u,v,l:r*=8s*=8u*=8v*=8l*=8z=0REPEATz+=1E-3UNTILFNs(z)/z>=SQR(l^2-(v-s)^2)/(u-r)a=(u-r)/2/z
  p=(r+u-a*LN((l+v-s)/(l-v+s)))/2q=(v+s-l*FNc(z)/FNs(z))/2MOVE800,0DRAW0,0DRAW0,800CIRCLEu,v,8CIRCLEr,s,8FORx=r TOu
    DRAW x,a*FNc((x-p)/a)+q
  NEXT
  DEFFNs(t)=(EXP(t)-EXP(-t))/2
  DEFFNc(t)=(EXP(t)+EXP(-t))/2
```

Emulator at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/bbcwin.html

This has obviously been solved before, so the first thing I did was look what others have done.

The equation of a catenary centred at the origin is simply `y=a*cosh(x/a)`. It becomes slightly more complicated if it is not centred at the origin.

Various sources say that if the length and endpoints are known the value for `a` must be determined numerically. There is an unspecified parameter `h` in the wikipedia article. So I found another site and basically followed the method here: [http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/99_incoming/catenary](http://www.math.niu.edu/%7Erusin/known-math/99_incoming/catenary)

BBC Basic does not have `sinh` and `cosh` built in, so I defined two functions at the end of the program to calculate them using `EXP`

coordinates for lefthand point must be supplied before righthand point, OP confirmed this is OK. Length is given last. Values can be separated by commas or newlines.

**Ungolfed code**

```
  INPUT r,s,u,v,l

  REM convert input in range 0-100 to graphic coordinates in range 0-800 
  r*=8 s*=8 u*=8 v*=8 l*=8

  REM solve for z numerically
  z=0
  REPEAT
    z+=1E-3
  UNTIL FNs(z)/z>=SQR(l^2-(v-s)^2)/(u-r)

  REM calculate the curve parameters
  a=(u-r)/2/z
  p=(r+u-a*LN((l+v-s)/(l-v+s)))/2
  q=(v+s-l*FNc(z)/FNs(z))/2

  REM draw axes, 800 graphics units long = 400 pixels long (2 graphics units per pixel)
  MOVE 800,0
  DRAW 0,0
  DRAW 0,800

  REM draw markers at end and beginning of curve (beginning last, so that cursor is in right place for next step)
  CIRCLE u,v,8
  CIRCLE r,s,8

  REM draw curve from beginning to end
  FORx=r TOu
    DRAW x,a*FNc((x-p)/a)+q
  NEXT

  REM definitions of sinh and cosh
  DEF FNs(t)=(EXP(t)-EXP(-t))/2
  DEF FNc(t)=(EXP(t)+EXP(-t))/2
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7 + matplotlib, 424

Run as

```
python thisscript.py [length] [x0] [y0] [x1] [y1]
```

If I can assume that x0 is always smaller than x1 character count reduces to **398**

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import *
import sys
c=cosh
l,p,q,u,w=map(float,sys.argv[1:])
if p>u:
 p,q,u,w=u,w,p,q
h=u-p
v=w-q
a=brentq(lambda a:(2.*h/a*sinh(0.5*a))**2-l**2-v**2,1e-20,600)
b=brentq(lambda b:c(a*(1.-b))-c(a*b)-a*v/h,-600/a,600/a)
r=linspace(p,u,100)
plot([p,u],[q,w],'ro')
plot(r,h/a*c(((r-p)/h-b)*a)-h/a*c(a*b)+q,'k-')
gca().set_xlim((0,100))
gca().set_ylim((0,100))
show()
```

The magic number 600 you see appearing in some places is due to the fact that cosh(x) and sinh(x) start overflowing around x=710 (so 600 to keep some margin)

> Basically I solve the problem in the frame where the catenary goes
>  trough (0,0) and (x1-x0,(y1-y0)/(x1-x0)) and then remap to the original
>  frame. This improves the numerical stability **a lot**.